# PnP Modern Search V3 for Sharepoint Server

Tags: sharepoint-server, pnp

We are migrating to Sharepoint 2019 On-Premise, and tried installing PnP Modern Search V3, but I get an error message when trying to add the web part to a page.  Is PnP Modern Search V3 available for on-prem, or is it only available for the cloud version?

Comment: I am checking to see how things are going there on this issue.

Answer (score 1):

PnP modern search does not work on SharePoint 2019 due to an SPFx version limitation that affects SharePoint on-premises. Here are two GitHub threads from 2019 with answers from the creators of PnP modern search:

[Help Please!!! Modern Search WebPart Not working on SharePoint on-premise 2019](https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-solutions/issues/147#issuecomment-490559033)

[SP2019 on premise](https://github.com/microsoft-search/pnp-modern-search/issues/33#issuecomment-563975115)